# Vue2 Composition API: toRefs() TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2

In parent component I'm running foreach loop on a collection of objects and each loop is creating a component along with passing the object as props.

In child component, I'm trying to create a ref for a parent object. However, it is throwing the following error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at setup (app_vue.js?id=eb11add1a3bc688d0963:9333:69)


  setup: function setup(props) {
    var _toRefs = Object(vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["toRefs"])(props),
        person = _toRefs.person;
```

Below is the sample code

ParentComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <b-row align-h="center">
        <b-col cols="12">
            <b-tabs pills card vertical nav-wrapper-class="col-md-3 col-12">
                <b-tab v-for="(person, index) in forms.data.persons" :key="person.id">
                    <template #title>
                        {{ person.salutation }} {{ person.first_name }} {{ person.last_name }}
                    </template>
                    <ChildComponent :resourceId="resourceId" :forms="forms" :person="person" :index="index" :select2="select2" />
                </b-tab>
            </b-tabs>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
</template>

<script>
import useVuelidate from '@vuelidate/core'; requiredIf, email, url } from '@vuelidate/validators'
import ChildComponent from './Partials/ChildTabPill'

export default {
    name: "parent",
    props: ["resourceId", "resourceCode"],
    components: {
        ChildComponent,
    },
    setup () {
        return { v$: useVuelidate() };
    },
    data() {
        return {
            select2: {
                classifications: ['Loading...'],
                salutations: ['Loading...'],
                users: ['Loading...'],
            },
            forms: {
                urls: {
                    persons: {
                        update: `fakeUrl`,
                        delete: `fakeUrl`,
                    }
                },
                refs: {
                    persons: 'persons',
                },
                disabled: {
                    persons: false,
                },
                names: {
                    persons: 'Person',
                },
                data: {
                    persons: [],
                },
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.init()
    },
    methods: {
        init() {
            this.getPersons();
        },
        getPersons() {
            axios.get(`fakeurl`).then(response => {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    this.forms.data.persons = response.data
                }
            })
        },
        getSelect2Data() {
            axios.get('fakeUrl').then(response => { this.select2.classifications = response.data; })
            axios.get('fakeUrl').then(response => { this.select2.salutations = response.data; })
            axios.get('fakeUrl').then(response => { this.select2.users = response.data; })
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Child Component

```
    <template>
    <b-form class="form" :ref="forms.refs.persons + person.id + 'Form'" :id="forms.refs.persons + index + 'Form'"
        @submit.prevent="submitForm">
        <fieldset :disabled="forms.disabled['persons' + patient.id]">
            <b-row class="px-1">
                <b-col sm="12" lg="6" xl="4" class="px-2">
                    <b-card class="gutter-b card-custom card-stretch" body-class="px-1 px-md-3 py-3" header-class="p-5">
                        <template class="p-5" #header>
                            <h4>Personal Details</h4>
                            <b-button :href="`/crm/person/${patient.id}`" variant="primary">
                                <b-icon-eye-fill class="svg-icon" />View Person
                            </b-button>
                        </template>
                        <b-form-group label-class="pt-2 pb-1 label-required" label="Salutation">
                            <b-form-input v-model="patient.salutation" />
                        </b-form-group>
                        <b-form-group label-class="pt-2 pb-1 label-required" label="First Name">
                            <b-form-input type="text" v-model="patient.first_name" />
                        </b-form-group>
                        <b-form-group label-class="pt-2 pb-1 label-required" label="Last Name">
                            <b-form-input type="text" v-model="patient.last_name" />
                        </b-form-group>
                    </b-card>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
            <b-row align-h="end">
                <b-button type="button" variant="primary" @click="validate">
                    <b-icon-save-2 class="svg-icon" />Save
                </b-button>
            </b-row>
            <pre>{{ v$ }}</pre>
        </fieldset>
    </b-form>
</template>
<script>
import useVuelidate from '@vuelidate/core';
import { required } from '@vuelidate/validators';
import { toRefs } from 'vue';

export default {
    name: "child-component",
    props: {
        resourceId: String,
        forms: {type: Object, default: () => []},
        person: { type: Object, default: () => []},
        index: Number,
        select2: {type: Object, default: () => []},
    },
    setup(props) {
        const { person } = toRefs(props);
        const rules = {
            person: {
                salutation: {
                    $lazy: true,
                    $autoDirty: true,
                    required,
                },
                first_name: {
                    $lazy: true,
                    $autoDirty: true,
                    required,
                },
                last_name: {
                    $lazy: true,
                    $autoDirty: true,
                    required,
                },
            }
        };
        return { v$: useVuelidate(rules, { person }) };
    },
    methods: {
        validate() {
            console.log(this.v$.person);
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            patient: this.person,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: why are you using both composition API and options API, they are completely different, you should use only one!!!

Comment: This is against all Vue principles, no wonder why you have bugs

Comment: @Sonny49 I'm kinda new to VueJs, and has been using it for about a month. Could you please explain where and how I'm using both composition API and options API. So I can have better understading and debug it.

Comment: you can read here: https://fjolt.com/article/vue-composition-api-vs-options-api
and chose to use either one. Once you mix them you will make simple things complicated.

Comment: @Sonny49 Now I get it, composition API was introduced in Vue3. And I'm using Vue@2.6.14 and it does support only options API.
I was following the documentation of Vuelidate@2.x and in that it was explained in composition API. However, vuelidate does support both Vue2 and Vue3.
In this case could you please explain how should I do the validation in child component?
I have a demo app on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-flower-c65sc6?file=/src/components/Profile.vue).